# Subtract Expression JSON

Tags: json, angular

Update: I am trying to do subtract expression in JSON file.

```
export const PRODUCTS: Products[] = [
{
    id: 1,
    productCat:'Product Cat',
    product: [
        {
            productName: 'Product Name',
            newPrice: 800,
            oldPrice: 1000,
            save: 'oldPrice' - 'newPrice'
        },
    ],
}
]
```

I am new to JSON so I dont know if it's even possible. If there is any other way please help.

Comment: 1) This is not valid JSON, you must use double quotes `"`. 2) What kind of programming language or environment do you want to use?

Comment: Hello @LutzHorn I have updated my question can you please help. I am using it in angular 4

Comment: This question seems unrelated to JSON in spite that it is mentioned several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `forEach` function to add `save` key. like this

```js
const PRODUCTS = [{
  id: 1,
  productCat: 'Product Cat',
  product: [{
      productName: 'Product Name',
      newPrice: 800,
      oldPrice: 1000
    },
    {
      name: 'Product Name 2',
      newPrice: 1800,
      oldPrice: 10000
    }
  ],
}];


PRODUCTS[0].product.forEach(itm => itm['save'] = itm['oldPrice'] - itm['newPrice']);

console.log(PRODUCTS);
```

Comment: This is a correct answer if we assume the question is about JavaScript. But the OP tells us nothing about the programming language to use.

Comment: Hello @Saeed.Ataee I have updated my question can you please help again. I am using it in angular 4

Comment: add `Products` to first of product variable. `PRODUCTS[0].product.forEach` @Akshay